# No output from Storm bolt

Tags: apache-storm

I have a very simple Storm bolt that takes input from a Kafka spout and should just write to standard output.  It extends BaseRichBolt.  The two pertinent methods are:

```
  public void prepare(Map stormConfig,
                      TopologyContext context,
                      OutputCollector collector)
    {
    collector_ = collector;
    logger_.info("TestEchoBolt prepared.");
    System.out.println("TestEchoBolt prepared.");
    }

  public void execute(Tuple input)
    {
    logger_.info(input.getFields().toString());
    System.out.println(input.getFields().toString());
    collector_.ack(input);
    }
```

It's wired up like this:

```
    builder_ = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder_.setSpout("kafka-spout",kafkaSpout,1);
    builder_.setBolt("echo-bolt",echoBolt)
            .shuffleGrouping("kafka-spout");
```

I see output from the constructor when I submit the topology to a cluster running on my local machine, but I never see any output from the bolt.  The Storm UI shows tuples being emitted, executed, and acked, with no errors.

Where's my output?

(This is Storm 0.9.5 and Kafka 0.8.2.1.)

Comment: System.out should be redirected to the worker log files.

Comment: storm.local.dir is set to "/tmp/storm", but I don't see any log files in the worker directory.

Comment: Log files are located in $STORM_HOME/logs (storm.local.dir is for internal execution stuff)

Comment: That was it.  I needed to set storm.log.dir to get them where I want.  Thanks!

Comment: How about leaving self answer and accept it so that others can have a great reference?

Comment: Okay, but I'd like Matthias to get the credit.  What's the protocol here?

Comment: In order to give Matthias a credit, Matthias should write an answer. Upvoting his comment may also give a credit, but I don't know how many.

Answer (score 1):

Matthias had the correct answer in the comments.  All output goes to $STORM_HOME/logs unless the storm.log.dir property is set in $STORM_HOME/conf/storm.yaml.

The output will be in the .../logs/worker-*.log files.